# Arranging shapes into a similar shape

Tags: pattern, geometry, tiling, packing

The goals if possible.

**Goal 1.**
In the image there are 12 shapes each containing 15 cells.

Take any 3 shapes from the set and arrange them into any new shape, 2 example shapes that you could use are given in the image.

Take any 3 of the remaining pieces and try and create the exact same shape

Repeat by taking another 3 pieces and building the same shape again

Goal achieved!!!
3 new identical shapes each containing 45 cells.

Bonus if the last 3 pieces can make the same shape too.

Note
When making a shape at least 1 cell needs to be orthogonally touching 1 cell of another shape
Rotation and reflection of the pieces is allowed

**Goal 2**
Is it possible to create a target shape that can always be made no matter what 3 shapes have been selected.?

If not
How about if 4 of the pieces are selected would it be possible then?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. When you say, "The goals if possible" does that mean you have no idea whether this is possible? I ask because with most sets of pieces like this, it's rare to be able to make multiple congruent shapes unless the solution is "planted", ie you selected the shapes specifically for the purpose. Others might be able to tell quickly by inspection, but for me to try to solve this involves a ton of work. I have techniques that work to find sets of pieces that tile congruent shapes, eg "using any of the 15-ominos find 4 distinct sets of three that tile the same shape"

Comment: I dont know if its possible.. but I have specifically chosen these shapes for a reason

Comment: If I get a chance I'll try and tile a few simple shapes with some of the 3.4 million 15-ominos to look for a set of disjoint triples that tile a 5x9 rectangle. Might give you an idea of how unlikely your set is...

Comment: I dont think a 5x9 rectangle will work at all.

Comment: Not sure why you would say that. I took about 1/8 of the 15-ominos and tiled them into a 4x5 then ran a clique search on the triples. It found a clique of 21 disjoint triples in a few minutes. I'll tile them into a 105x9 if possible and you can have a crack at finding the clique.

Comment: "but I have specifically chosen these shapes for a reason" ah OK then if you did your job well there might be a shape that works. I can think of an algorithm for finding such shapes but I'm not game to try and code it...